# Bootstrap drop-down submit form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am not able to submit my dropdown values to my php page.

I tried to makeit via javascripts but its not working.

Here is the code `

```
    <div class="col-md-6"><h5>Select your desired shape</h5></div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
    <input class="span2" id="search_type" name="search_type" type="hidden" >
    <div class="btn-group" name="shape" id="shape">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" name="shape">
               <span data-bind="label">Shapes</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
             </button>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" name="shape">
               <li onclick="$('#search_type').val('sphere'); $('#submitForm').submit()"><a href="#"> Sphere</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Cylinder</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Cube</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Cuboid</a></li>
             </ul>
           </div>

    </div>

</div>`
```

And form declaration is

`<form action="submit.php" name="submitForm" id="submit" method="post" role="form" id="submitForm">`

I am not able to resolve it.

If possible give me some examples for bootstrap form which includes the dropdown values.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working:

```
<div class="col-md-6"><h5>Select your desired shape</h5></div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
    <input class="span2" id="search_type" name="search_type" type="hidden" >
    <div class="btn-group" name="shape" id="shape">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" name="shape">
               <span data-bind="label">Shapes</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
             </button>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" name="shape">
               <li onclick="$(alert('it works!')).val('sphere'); $('#submitForm').submit()"><a href="#"> Sphere</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Cylinder</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Cube</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Cuboid</a></li>
             </ul>
           </div>

    </div>

</div>`
```

Some things to keep in mind when getting started with PHP is that if you are running locally you have to type the address into the address bar to kick the php into gear you cannot just open the index.php file and expect the php to work.

But again, your front-end is working. Your PHP is off.

Perhaps adding `<li onclick input type="submit" method= "post" action="phpfile" name="sphere"><a href="index.php"> Sphere</a></li>`

This brings up another potential issue. Will you need Ajax for the front-end? The way it is now the user will submit and be redirected from your page to a new page. Is the goal to keep them on the page? That will require a few more files then a bootstrap index and a little php.

I hope this helps.